# The specified module 'updateScript' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: powershell

I am getting following error whenever I start PowerShell on Window's 10 machine.

```
import-module : The specified module 'updateScript' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1:48 char:1
+ import-module updateScript
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (updateScript:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

get-newScript : The term 'get-newScript' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1:49 char:1
+ get-newScript -scriptPath $scripts
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-newScript:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This is the first time I tried to use PowerShell on that machine. There are no errors on other machines of similar configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have something within your profile. Just run `ii $profile`. A text file should open where you probably have to remove these commands...